# Block Specific PHP File in Specific Folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

In htaccess, I want to block this;

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/src/config/db.php
```

but not this;

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/src/config/settings.php
```

**THIS SOLVED;**

```
<Files "db.php"> Order Allow,Deny Deny from all </Files>
```

Comment: To deny access to a single uri 
`RedirectMatch 403 ^/src/config/db.php$` should work.

Comment: Thanks. This also solved my problem